# Drupal 404 redirect to a custom PHP file

Tags: redirection, .htaccess

Is there any possibility to redirect Drupal 404 to a custom php file without sending actual 404 headers.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse there is a module for this too.. !!!

[Search 404](https://www.drupal.org/project/search404) Module would help you achieve this

> Instead of showing a standard "404 Page not found", this module performs a search on the keywords in the URL
>
> It also has Support for Custom Text and Title to be displayed in search404 pages